# What is best way to save user's data to carry through the website pages in PHP?

Tags: php, security

What is the best way to carry users data through the pages(php)? Currently, I use sessions to hold and use data like username, lastlogin, password, purchased items and ... between the website pages.

Would saving these data in sessions decrease security of website? Is there another way(s) to carry these data?

Comment: Databases, static files, cookies... there are numerous options. `"Best way"` is too subjective though... Depends on how much data and how persistent you need the data to be... etc...

Comment: cookies would decrease security a d*** sight more - what makes you think using sessions is insecure?

Comment: @Lix: Which one is more secure? Will using sessions make security problems?

Comment: why would storing things in a session decrease security? sessions are (arguably) far more secure than any other method you could care to use, since they're purely a server-side construct.

Comment: Please base your inquiry on a link/reference where you took your security speculation from, otherwise hard to answer.

Comment: SO has turned into "who closes the question first" contest apparently. Time to go and build a better clone I guess.

Comment: @ima - Every method has its advantages and disadvantages - you will be able to make each method as secure as you want it to be. It all depends on how you implement it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the persistent data (which need to be preserved even if user closes the browser) into database.

Save everthing else into session.

As for cookies, please note that it gets sent back and forth with each request. I don't recommend using cookies, except maybe for session ID.